# Query the list of city names starting and ending with vowels(i.e. a,e,i,o,u). no duplicates. Alternative process

Tags: sql

I could run it by using like operator and regexp but I want to know why the below written code is not working.

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where lower(substr(CITY,1,length(CITY)))in("a","e","i","o","u");
```

Comment: `substr` wants position,length not length,position. `substr(city,-1)` may be fractionally faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd probably go with either of the two options:

```
substr(city,-1)
```

(as posted earlier), or as I find more "intuitive"

```
substr(city, length(city), 1)
```

Note: If you're coming from a programming language like Python you'd be tempted to do a length(string)-1, but this would not work here.